# Getting frequency values from histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram, frequency

I know how to draw histograms or other frequency/percentage related tables.
But now I want to know, how can I get those frequency values in a table to use after the fact.

I have a massive dataset, now I draw a histogram with a set binwidth. I want to extract the frequency value (i.e. value on y-axis) that corresponds to each binwidth and save it somewhere.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 59):

The `hist` function has a return value (an object of class `histogram`):

```
R> res <- hist(rnorm(100))
R> res
$breaks
[1] -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4

$counts
[1]  1  2 17 27 34 16  2  1

$intensities
[1] 0.01 0.02 0.17 0.27 0.34 0.16 0.02 0.01

$density
[1] 0.01 0.02 0.17 0.27 0.34 0.16 0.02 0.01

$mids
[1] -3.5 -2.5 -1.5 -0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5

$xname
[1] "rnorm(100)"

$equidist
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

Comment: Aaaah, just got the same idea and wanted to post this! You were faster :-)

Comment: You shall also note that he should use `plot = FALSE`, so that he only gets results without plotting the histogram.

Comment: is there a way without hist?
I am trying to make hist with custom breaks and it doesn't work. Could there be something else?

Comment: @xealits: `table(cut(rnorm(100), breaks=c(-Inf, -1, 1, Inf)))`

Answer (score 23):

From `?hist`:
Value

an object of class "histogram" which is a list with components:

- breaks    the n+1 cell boundaries (= breaks if that was a vector).
  These are the nominal breaks, not with the boundary fuzz.
- counts   n integers; for each cell, the number of x[] inside.
- density   values f^(x[i]), as estimated density values. If
  all(diff(breaks) == 1), they are the relative frequencies counts/n
  and in general satisfy sum[i; f^(x[i]) (b[i+1]-b[i])] = 1, where b[i]
  = breaks[i].
- intensities   same as density. Deprecated, but retained for
  compatibility.
- mids  the n cell midpoints.
- xname     a character string with the actual x argument name.
- equidist  logical, indicating if the distances between breaks are all
  the same.

`breaks` and `density` provide just about all you need:

```
histrv<-hist(x)
histrv$breaks
histrv$density
```

Answer (score 14):

Just in case someone hits this question with `ggplot`'s `geom_histogram` in mind, note that there is a way to extract the data from a ggplot object.

The following convenience function outputs a dataframe with the lower limit of each bin (`xmin`), the upper limit of each bin (`xmax`), the mid-point of each bin (`x`), as well as the frequency value (`y`).

```
## Convenience function
get_hist <- function(p) {
    d <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
    data.frame(x = d$x, xmin = d$xmin, xmax = d$xmax, y = d$y)
}

# make a dataframe for ggplot
set.seed(1)
x = runif(100, 0, 10)
y = cumsum(x)
df <- data.frame(x = sort(x), y = y)

# make geom_histogram 
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = cumsum(..count..)), binwidth = 1, boundary = 0,
                color = "black", fill = "white")
```

Illustration:

```
hist = get_hist(p)
head(hist$x)
## [1] 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5
head(hist$y)
## [1]  7 13 24 38 52 57
head(hist$xmax)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
head(hist$xmin)
## [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

A related question I answered here ([Cumulative histogram with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356860/cumulative-histogram-with-ggplot2/47082374#47082374)).