# Cumulative histogram with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How could I get a cumulative histogram like this

```
x <- runif(100,0,10)
h <- hist(x)
h[["counts"]] <- cumsum(h[["counts"]])
plot(h)
```

with ggplot2?

I want also to draw a polygon like this

```
lines(h[["breaks"]],c(0,h[["counts"]]))
```

[image]

Comment: How about adding the plot as an image?

Comment: In my answer below I gave replication a shot. You can get even closer with ``theme_bw()``  or ``theme_classic()``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Didzis's answer, here's a way to get the `ggplot2` (author: hadley) data into a `geom_line` to reproduce the look of the `base R hist`.

Brief explanation: to get the bins to position in the same way as base R, I set `binwidth=1` and `boundary=0`. To get a similar look, I used `color=black` and `fill=white`. And to get the same position of the line segments, I used `ggplot_build`. You will find other answers by Didzis that use this trick.

```
# make a dataframe for ggplot
set.seed(1)
x = runif(100, 0, 10)
y = cumsum(x)
df <- data.frame(x = sort(x), y = y)

# make geom_histogram 
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = cumsum(..count..)), binwidth = 1, boundary = 0,
                color = "black", fill = "white")

# extract ggplot data
d <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

# make a data.frame for geom_line and geom_point
# add (0,0) to mimick base-R plots
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(0, d$xmax), y = c(0, d$y))

# combine plots: note that geom_line and geom_point use the new data in df2
p + geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y),
        color = "darkblue", size = 1) +
    geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y),
        color = "darkred", size = 1) +
    ylab("Frequency") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 2))

# save for posterity
ggsave("ggplot-histogram-cumulative-2.png")
```

There may be easier ways mind you! As it happens the ggplot object also stores two other values of `x`: the minimum and the maximum. So you can make other polygons with this convenience function:

```
# Make polygons: takes a plot object, returns a data.frame
get_hist <- function(p, pos = 2) {
    d <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
    if (pos == 1) { x = d$xmin; y = d$y; }
    if (pos == 2) { x = d$x; y = d$y; }
    if (pos == 3) { x = c(0, d$xmax); y = c(0, d$y); }
    data.frame(x = x, y = y)
}
df2 = get_hist(p, pos = 3)  # play around with pos=1, pos=2, pos=3
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I do know the question is 4 years old, but I was looking for a way to do this and ended up working it out myself. As it took me a bit of effort, I thought I'd share it here.

Answer (score 24):

To make cumulative histogram use `geom_histogram()` and then use `cumsum(..count..)` for `y` values. Cumulative line can be added with `stat_bin()` and `geom="line"` and `y` values calculated as `cumsum(..count..)`.

```
ggplot(NULL,aes(x))+geom_histogram(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)))+
       stat_bin(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="line",color="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to draw a polygon like the one in the question?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, but this is not exactly what I need. If you observe carefully the polygon in the question, each segment end at the upper right corner of the bar, not in the middle.

Comment: If someone wonders where that magic ..count.. comes from, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc