# "Density" curve overlay on histogram where vertical axis is frequency (aka count) or relative frequency?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a method to overlay something analogous to a density curve when the vertical axis is frequency or relative frequency?  (Not an actual density function, since the area need not integrate to 1.)  The following question is similar:
[ggplot2: histogram with normal curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967664/ggplot2-histogram-with-normal-curve), and the user self-answers with the idea to scale `..count..` inside of `geom_density()`.  However this seems unusual.

The following code produces an overinflated "density" line.

```
df1            <- data.frame(v = rnorm(164, mean = 9, sd = 1.5))
b1             <- seq(4.5, 12, by = 0.1)
hist.1a        <- ggplot(df1, aes(v)) + 
                    stat_bin(aes(y = ..count..), color = "black", fill = "blue",
                             breaks = b1) + 
                    geom_density(aes(y = ..count..))
hist.1a
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

@joran's response/comment got me thinking about what the appropriate scaling factor would be.  For posterity's sake, here's the result.

**When Vertical Axis is Frequency (aka Count)**

[image: density]

Thus, the scaling factor for a vertical axis measured in bin counts is

[image: bincount]

In this case, with `N = 164` and the bin width as `0.1`, the aesthetic for y in the smoothed line should be:

```
y = ..density..*(164 * 0.1)
```

Thus the following code produces a "density" line scaled for a histogram measured in frequency (aka count).

```
df1            <- data.frame(v = rnorm(164, mean = 9, sd = 1.5))
b1             <- seq(4.5, 12, by = 0.1)
hist.1a        <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = v)) + 
                    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), breaks = b1, 
                                   fill = "blue", color = "black") + 
                    geom_density(aes(y = ..density..*(164*0.1)))
hist.1a
```

[image: plot]

**When Vertical Axis is Relative Frequency**

[image: relfreq]

Using the above, we could write

```
hist.1b        <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = v)) + 
                    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../164), breaks = b1, 
                                   fill = "blue", color = "black") + 
                    geom_density(aes(y = ..density..*(0.1)))
hist.1b
```

[image: relf]

**When Vertical Axis is Density**

```
hist.1c        <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = v)) + 
                    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), breaks = b1, 
                                   fill = "blue", color = "black") + 
                    geom_density(aes(y = ..density..))
hist.1c
```

[image: dens]

Comment: Is it possible to extract the value of this ```..density..```?

Comment: @amrrs, See here on how to extract the histogram values. Similar hackery will get you the density (but there may be an easier way). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740503/getting-frequency-values-from-histogram-in-r/47137411#47137411

Comment: @Pat W. This is a great answer. A very minor comment: to get the density curve without the vertical bits on the edges and the horizontal line contour, here's a way: ``geom_line(aes(y = ..density..), stat = "density", lwd=1)``, where ``lwd`` can be tweaked to thicken the line, if so desired.

Comment: You can also use something like `geom_density(aes(y = ..count..*0.1))`, where you only need the bin width, not the number of bins

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x = v)) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(y = ..ncount..)) + 
   geom_density(aes(y = ..scaled..))
```

Comment: Would you know how to do it if we didn't want to scale the count to 1?

Comment: @PatW. A smooth density estimate and binned counts are not on the same scale (as you observed in your first attempt). To align them, you'll have to place them on the same scale. You can adjust that scale to be whatever you like, but some adjustment will be required.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)
smoothedHistogram <- function(dat, y, bins=30, xlabel = y, ...){
  gg <- ggplot(dat, aes_string(y)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins=bins, center = 0.5, stat="bin", 
                   fill = I("midnightblue"), color = "#E07102", alpha=0.8) 
  gg_build <- ggplot_build(gg)
  area <- sum(with(gg_build[["data"]][[1]], y*(xmax - xmin)))
  gg <- gg + 
    stat_density(aes(y=..density..*area), 
                 color="#BCBD22", size=2, geom="line", ...)
  gg$layers <- gg$layers[2:1]
  gg + xlab(xlabel) +  
    theme_bw() + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
                       axis.text = element_text(size = 12))
}
```

---

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000))
smoothedHistogram(dat, "x")
```

[image]