Why can't I get counts on my y-axis on geom_density?
I am trying to do 4 different plots with geom_density and put the count on my y-axis, then put them together with ggarrange. I am following this to be able to put count on my y-axis: Density plots with counts
Here is my data:
structure(list(group = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), value = c(112.306866666667, 
78.2724666666667, 0.339703333333333, 3.76666666666667, 146.513433333333, 
162.5825, 6.93333333333333, 176.8, 175.4, 6.93333333333333, 6.06, 
129.990666666667, 119.521666666667, 12.55, 161.6, 121.4, 0, 19.65, 
172.337166666667, 184.2535, 27.7333333333333, 140.5034, 108.5384, 
0.496946666666667, 12.35, 265, 184.2, 0, 55.8, 105.2671, 123.542766666667, 
32.7166666666667, 194.4, 206, 0, 29.55, 144, 162.666666666667, 
4.73333333333333, 134.333333333333, 113, 0.666666666666667, 5.6, 
186, 193.666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 10, 261.333333333333, 
184, 8.63333333333333, 140.666666666667, 110.333333333333, 2.06666666666667, 
92, 158, 1.1, 70.6666666666667, 63.6666666666667, 2.73333333333333, 
98.6666666666667, 77.6666666666667, 42.4666666666667, 102.666666666667, 
80.3333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 108, 173.666666666667, 0, 
984.083333333333, 186.666666666667, 150, 7.75, 140, 138.666666666667, 
3.31666666666667, 121, 79.6666666666667, 4.41666666666667, 171.4405, 
160.749233333333, 21.65, 180, 120, 0, 17.1, 162.867666666667, 
128.443833333333, 24.6833333333333, 172, 114, 0.6, 18.65, 81, 
72.3333333333333, 24.6, 143.666666666667, 70.6666666666667, 4.51666666666667, 
138.333333333333, 153.666666666667, 12, 0.05, 195, 163, 0.666666666666667, 
10.7666666666667, 76.6666666666667, 82, 0.333333333333333, 49.2833333333333, 
92, 53, 0.333333333333333, 30.8666666666667, 62, 38, 0, 3.06666666666667, 
102, 114.666666666667, 3.43333333333333, 42.6666666666667, 40, 
0.466666666666667, 107.333333333333, 224.666666666667, 0, 28.3666666666667, 
132, 142, 0, 16.0833333333333, 142, 146, 17.4333333333333, 78.6666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 11.6333333333333, 59.3333333333333, 99, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 75, 67, 3.66666666666667, 57.7833333333333, 112, 74.6, 0.6, 
98.92, 116, 72.3333333333333, 0, 17.7666666666667, 134.8, 76.6, 
0, 25.38, 115.666666666667, 138.666666666667, 6.5, 125.4454, 
71.9361, 0.04383, 29.4751166666667, 109.333333333333, 133, 0, 
42.4079666666667, 137.810433333333, 112.988866666667, 8.405845, 
36.6666666666667, 41.3333333333333, 0, 27.9833333333333, 32.44961, 
35.7635666666667, 0.0935366666666667, 7.01737, 163.333333333333, 
170.666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 21.7884666666667, 171, 161.333333333333, 
6.71666666666667, 119.333333333333, 79.6666666666667, 7, 1.8, 
148.666666666667, 238, 0.333333333333333, 17.95, 1, 50.3333333333333, 
0, 0), type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Control", 
"Case"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 199L), class = "data.frame")

It seems that only one of the plots gets the correct count (group 3), the rest have values under 1. I figured out that this has to do with the value of the bandwith of histograms after doing some searching. EDIT: as per this link:"Density" curve overlay on histogram where vertical axis is frequency (aka count) or relative frequency?
I found out that if I multiply with the default value 30
geom_density(aes(y=after_stat(count)*30)

I get the "correct" answer on the 3 plots where I get my y-axis under 1. Now my question is: Where do I extract that bandwidth constant where I multiply the count with so I can automate my plots? I am doing for loops for 5 other datasets as well and I want everything automated. My code is the following
plot_list <- list()
for(j in 1:length(unique(data1$group))){
  
  tmp_data <- data1[data1$group == j,]
  
  plot_list[[j]] <- ggplot(tmp_data, aes(x = value, fill = type)) +
                           geom_density(aes(y=after_stat(count)), alpha = 0.6) + 
                           ylab("Frequency") + theme_minimal() 
}


It's not clear what you are after. If you are estimating a kernel density function with geom_density, that has nothing to do with actual observed counts. A density function allows you to integrate the area under the curve to estimate probabilities. It doesn't make sense to have a continuous line represent counts. What exactly are you trying to show in this plot?

If you try my code you will see that the count on the y-axis is incorrect for 3 of the 4 plots. But if I multiply it with 30 it will be correct for those since the default bandwith of histograms is 30. Does it make sense?

The "counts" on the y-axis are incorrect for all of the plots because the y-axis does not represent the original counts. You are not making a histogram - you are making a density plot.

Yes I know that Edward. But I have no other explaination why I get the correct count on the y-axis on 3 out of the 4 plots if I multiply it with a factor of 30, which is the defualt values of the amount of bins for histograms.
I know that histograms have nothing to do with geom_density. But I know they are somehow connected as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611438/density-curve-overlay-on-histogram-where-vertical-axis-is-frequency-aka-count. I have edited my original text by adding this link as well

This way you won't have to calculate a scaling factor:
ggplot(data1, aes(x = value, 
  y = after_stat(count), 
  colour = group, fill = type)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.6) + 
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free")


Thank you for your answer, however this does not work for me. I still get the wrong scaling on my y-axis with this code.

What do you expect to see that makes the values "wrong"?

Hi Michiel, when you try to create the plots. You see that the count on the y-axis is incorrect. In 3 out of the 4 plots, you will see that the count on the y-axis is actually below 1 whenever you multiply with that given constant. You can try tot create a histogram and then you add a geom_density object upon it you will see that it doesn't work. Now I believe that the constant can be extracted by what was written here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611438/density-curve-overlay-on-histogram-where-vertical-axis-is-frequency-aka-count
but I can't get that to work either.
