# geom_histogram: What is the default origin of the first bin?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to know the default origin of the first bin in a histogram created with `ggplot2` for a given bin width. Unfortunately, I did not find any information at the help pages of `geom_histogram`, `geom_bar`, and `stat_bin`. Please find below a minimal example for a histogram with `ggplot2`.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 x <- rnorm(25)
 binwidth <- (range(x)[2]-range(x)[1])/10
 ggplot(data.frame(x=x), aes(x = x)) +
   geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = binwidth)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the histogram is centered at 0, and the first bars xlimits are at `0.5*binwidth` and `-0.5*binwidth`. From there, the bars continue with `width = binwidth` in both directions until they hit the minimum and maximum. Or, if you data is all > 0, they start at the first `(x+0.5)*binwidth` that contains data.

For your example (using a set.seed for reproducibility):

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(25)
binwidth <- (range(x)[2]-range(x)[1])/10
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=x), aes(x = x)) +
   geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = binwidth)
```

We can get the breaks out by using:

```
x1 <- ggplot_build(p)$data
```

giving us our breaks:

```
x1[[1]]$x
 [1] -2.4764874 -2.0954894 -1.7144913 -1.3334932 -0.9524952 -0.5714971 -0.1904990  0.1904990  0.5714971
[10]  0.9524952  1.3334932  1.7144913  2.0954894
```

So, to get the minimum, we need to round the lowest value of the data to a multiple of binwidth + 0.5 (NB I'm sure there is a better formula, but this works):

```
binwidth*(floor((min(x)-binwidth/2)/binwidth)+0.5)
-2.476487
```

similarly the maximum is:

```
binwidth*(ceiling((max(x)+binwidth/2)/binwidth)+0.5)
2.095489
```

Comment: Related answer, which shows how to get ``xmin`` along the lines of jeremycg's answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740503/getting-frequency-values-from-histogram-in-r/47137411#47137411