# Getting values from histogram with image

Tags: r, image-processing, histogram

How to get the values of histogram with image as parameter.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740503/getting-frequency-values-from-histogram-in-r), the values can be retrieved because hist() returns a value.

The rest of the code works fine. However, null is returned to histogram (full code):

```
library(EBImage)
image = readImage("cat.png")
grayImage <- channel(image,"gray")
grayScaled = floor(grayImage * 255)
histogram <- hist(grayScaled)

> histogram
NULL
```

Package EBImage is used here. So I want to get the intensities or counts like histogram$counts but the variable histogram is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EBImage` has registered a method for the generic `hist()` as can be seen here:

```
library("EBImage")
findMethodSignatures(hist)
     x          
[1,] "AffyBatch"
[2,] "ANY"      
[3,] "Image"
```

that is the reason why you can't return an `histogram`-class object when you call `hist(grayScaled)`. 
It depends a bit on what you want, but you can access the `.Data` slot of your  `image` object (which contains a matrix) and plot that, returning the desired object:

```
histogram <- hist(imageData(grayScaled))
```

Comment: I was also thinking of detaching the package before running histogram: `detach("package:EBImage", unload=TRUE)`.

Comment: Nice idea, in my example it yields the same result. Do you know how hist identifies the data slot without having the class-definiton of `image` registered?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys!

Comment: @DavidH Rather than reading the `.Data` slot directly, the `imageData` accessor should be used to get/set the pixel array of an `Image` object. The advantage of such an approach is that the `imageData` function works on both formal S4 `Image` objects, as well as on plain `array`s which might be used to store image data.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the accessor; thanks, updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from *EBImage* **version 4.13.5**, the method `hist()` for `Image` objects returns a (list of) `histogram-class` object(s). In case of images of colormode `Grayscale` the result is a single object of class `histogram`, and for `Color` images the result is a named list with elements corresponding to the red, green, and blue channels, as illustrated by the following example.

```
library(EBImage)

file  = system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage")
image = readImage(file)

h = hist(image)

str(h)
```

This feature is currently available in the devel branch of the package. It can be obtained from  [GitHub](https://github.com/aoles/EBImage):

```
devtools::install_github("aoles/EBImage")
```