# Getting bin width of a histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I've made a histogram as follows:

```
data(mtcars)
hist(mtcars$disp)
```

How do I find out the bin width in the above histogram?

Regards

Comment: Related: [Getting frequency values from histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740503/getting-frequency-values-from-histogram-in-r) (in the sense that both answers describes the elements of an object of class `histogram`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R does a number of  things by default in creating a histogram

You can print out this parameters of the histogram by
assigning to an an objec `histinfo` and then printing:

breaks will give you the bin width:

```
histinfo<-hist(mtcars$disp)
histinfo
```

```
> histinfo
$breaks
 [1]  50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500

$counts
[1] 5 7 4 1 4 4 4 1 2

$density
[1] 0.003125 0.004375 0.002500 0.000625 0.002500 0.002500 0.002500
[8] 0.000625 0.001250

$mids
[1]  75 125 175 225 275 325 375 425 475

$xname
[1] "mtcars$disp"

$equidist
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the result of the `hist()` call, then extract the breaks:

```r
h <- hist(mtcars$disp)
```

[image]

```r
h$breaks
#>  [1]  50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500
# To get the widths, use diff().  Here all are the same:
unique(diff(h$breaks))
#> [1] 50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Thanks to @BenBolker for the suggestion to calculate the width explicitly.